# InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type

Tags: arrays, string, exception, unity-game-engine, boo

I have fetched the data from xml and stored it in an array.I have coded as below

```
Private var dataarray=new Array();
private var timearray=new Array();
private var distancearray=new Array();
private var detailStock : String;
private var distancedata : String;
private var timedata : String;
private var datalist : String;
private var data : String;

 function readMe() {

var filepath : String = Application.dataPath+"/XmlDocs/"+"Stock"+".xml";
var xmlDoc : XmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
if(File.Exists (filepath))
{
    xmlDoc.Load( filepath );
    var Stock_list : XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Stock"); 

    for(var i : int = 0; i < Stock_list.Count;i++)
    {
        // getting child nodes of stock, like Rice and Wheat in a list
        var StockItems_list : XmlNodeList = Stock_list.Item(i).ChildNodes;


        // running a loop through all items present in the stock
        for(var j : int = 0; j < StockItems_list.Count; j++)  
        {
        //Debug.Log("StockItems_list count"+StockItems_list.Count);
            // taking the properties of a item into a list like Price and Quantity
            var StockItemsProperties_list : XmlNodeList =                      StockItems_list.Item(j).ChildNodes;

            for(var k : int = 0; k < StockItemsProperties_list.Count; k++)  
            {

            //Debug.Log("length....."+ StockItemsProperties_list[k].InnerText);
            data=StockItemsProperties_list[k].InnerText+"\t";
            //Debug.Log(data);




            /*--------Pushed the full data into an array-----------*/
           // dataarray=new Array();
            dataarray.Push(data);
        //Debug.Log("Elements in the array"+dataarray);





            }
            //var StockItemsProperties_list : XmlNodeList =StockItems_list[j].



            // Getting Names of Items like Rice and Wheat
            detailStock+="\n"+StockItems_list[j].Name+"\n";
            // We know that Price is stored at Oth element of StockItemsProperties_list
            detailStock+=StockItemsProperties_list[0].Name+"  ";
            // Inner Text of StockItemsProperties_list[0] (Price node) Contains the money
            detailStock+=StockItemsProperties_list[0].InnerText+" "+"Rs"+"\n";
            // And Quantity at 1st element of StockItemsProperties_list
            detailStock+=StockItemsProperties_list[1].Name+"  ";
            // Inner Text of StockItemsProperties_list[1] (Quantity node) Contains the Quantity in Kg
            detailStock+=StockItemsProperties_list[1].InnerText+" "+"Kg"+"\n";
            //Debug.Log("distance"+StockItemsProperties_list[0].InnerText);
            //Debug.Log("seconds"+StockItemsProperties_list[1].InnerText);



distancedata=StockItemsProperties_list[0].InnerText;
distancearray=new Array();
distancearray.Push(distancedata);
//Debug.Log("distance Array............ "+distancearray);


/*--------------Print the time into time array -----------------*/
timedata=StockItemsProperties_list[1].InnerText;
timearray=new Array();
timearray.Push(timedata);
// Debug.Log("time Array............ "+timearray);


/*-------------Distance and time from both array array ------------------*/
for(var d=0;d<distancearray.length;d++)
{

for(var t=0;t<timearray.length;t++)
{
 // Debug.Log("distance : " +distancearray[d] +"         "+"time:   "+timearray[t]+"\n");
transform.position-=new Vector3(0,distancearray[d],0);
 Debug.Log(transform.position);
}
}
```

With the above code Iam able to print the values.

But I want to move my object based on the values stored in the distancearray. transform.position-=new Vector3(0,distancearray[d],0);

the code for moving an object is getting the below exception

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.CheckNumericPromotion (IConvertible convertible)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.CheckNumericPromotion (System.Object value)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.UnboxSingle (System.Object value)
xmlDataReader.ReadXml () (at Assets/script/xmlDataReader.js:286)
xmlDataReader.OnGUI () (at Assets/script/xmlDataReader.js:141)
```

What will be the issue.Any problem with the variable declaration type?.Please help me out

Comment: Doesn't look like this has anything to do with javascript to me.

Comment: My guess is this is Typescript, not ordinary Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar   this is javascript

Comment: @user1509674 Javascript doesn't have type declarations.

Comment: @Barmar : I have put the exact code.Please help me out

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Typescript, I can't help you.

Comment: `: String` and `: int` are not Javascript. Javascript doesn't have type declarations like that.

Comment: Javascript also doesn't have `private` variables.

Comment: then how can I do it?

Comment: yes it is UnityScript.Could you help me out

Comment: It's definitely not Javascript, but is it really UnityScript? Because the exception points out that this is Bool.Lang.Runtime which refers to the third language Unity supports: Boo.

Answer (score 0):

This is UnityScript.

The issue is likely caused by distancedata being String, hence distancearray being array of String, not int.

Try this:

```html
private var distancedata : int;

...

distancedata = parseInt(StockItemsProperties_list[0].InnerText);
```

Though malformed XML can also be the reason.